# How to configure multiple ingresses in different namespaces on the same host

Tags: networking, kubernetes, dns, routes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a **single host** cluster with k8s and I would like to configure a Ingress for each namespace in order to create separated environment: one for production, one for development.
I also took 2 different domains.
When I deploy the production ingress there are no problems, but when I deploy the second ingress the dev environment is unreachable, using port-forward everything seems fine.

The 2 ingresses configuration:

Dev

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/redirect-to-https: "True"
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: '*.dev.cloud'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.dev.cloud'
    secretName: dev-cert
```

Production

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/redirect-to-https: "True"
  name: prod-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: '*.prod.cloud'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: "k8s-host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path/to/api
        backend:
          serviceName: web-api
          servicePort: 3000
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.prod.cloud'
    secretName: prod-cert
  - hosts:
    - "k8s-host"
    secretName: k8s-host-cert
```

I also edited the CNAME record of the 2 domains in order to redirect to the k8s host.

I was expecting that the request from a subdomain of one of the domain would be redirected to the ingress  matching the domain.

For example:

```
https://abc.dev.cloud -> dev-ingress
https://abc.prod.cloud -> prod-ingress
```

Comment: Is your "prod" environment in the `default` namespace?

Comment: Yes, it is, can it cause any kind of problem?

Comment: It shouldn't; I was more noticing that the `dev-ingress` was in the `dev` namespace and the `prod-ingress` didn't have a `namespace:` line.  But if it's supposed to be in `default` then that's correct.

Comment: Are there any issue you encounter with this ingress setup? It should work fine.